# Center of mass with function portions above and below the x-axis

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the $x$- and y-coordinates of the center of mass of a uniform ﬂat plate that is below the line $y = \sqrt{3x}$, above the line $y = − \sqrt{3x}$, and bounded on the right by the circle of radius $2$ centered at the origin.

I am having trouble figuring out where to start. Once I get the integral set up I can solve it, but I'm not sure how to begin. I tried setting up the integral in terms of $x$ by subtracting $y = \sqrt{3x}$ from $y = \sqrt{4 - x^2}$ and multiplying the integral of that by $2$ to find the area, but when I go to find the $x$-coordinate of the center of mass I get a completely wrong answer. Putting the equations in terms of $y$ and trying to solve it that way doesn't seem to work either. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

I haven't learned how to calculate in polar coordinates. Is there another way to calculate this without using that method? Also, the answer should come out to be 2√3/pi

Comment: I did not get your answer. Polar coordinates are simple. Just make change of coordinates $y=r\sin(\theta)$, $x=r\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: Finally after fixing mistakes I got your answer :)?

Answer (score 1):

EDITED
It's easier to caluclate in polar coordinates. $M_y$ is zero, but formally we can write
$$
M_y=\frac{1}{4\phi}\int_0^2 dr \int_{-\phi}^\phi r^2\sin \theta d\theta=0\\
M_x=\frac{1}{4\phi}\int_0^2 dr \int_{-\phi}^\phi r^2\cos \theta d\theta=\frac{1}{4\phi}r^3/3\big|_0^2\sin(\phi)\big|_{_\phi}^\phi\frac{4\sin(\phi)}{3\phi}
$$
Here $4\phi$ is the area of the figure.
Now regarding $\phi$. I think you made mistake $y=\sqrt{3}x$ and not $\sqrt{3x}$,since you have a straight line boundary.
Thus  $\phi=\arcsin(y/2)$, where $y^2+1/3 y^2=4$. So $y=\sqrt{3}$ and $\phi=\pi/3$;

Finally 
$$
M_x=\frac{4}{3\phi}\sin(\phi)=\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{\pi}
$$